# Multi user file property Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, automated-tests

I made autotest on Selenium. This test I will start on JMeter for load testing for 10, 20, 50+ users. What I should do. I create a property file (configuration file) and put there URL, Login, Password.
So I made a cycle and put there this code where I'll start my browser, login, visit link, logout and quit.
Here's what I have in property file:

```
URL:http://barracuda-qa.ko.kodak.com/d2l/faces/Login.jsp
Login:Test1, Test2, Tesr3
Password:Abc123
```

Here's my code in Java:

```
public class TestMultiply extends TestCase {
    File file = new File("C:/barracuda/prop.properties");
    private FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    private WebDriver driver;
    public FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    public int index=0;

    public TestMultiply(){}

    public TestMultiply(String testName){
        super(testName);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }


    @Test
    public void testTestLoad() throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        for (int i= 0; i<prop.getProperty("Login").length(); i++){
            //String login = prop.getProperty("Login"+i);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authLogin")).sendKeys(login);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authPassword")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty(key));
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:btnLogin")).click();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("settingsLink"));
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='logout']")).click();
                    driver.quit();
                }
            }); t1.start();  Thread.sleep(10000);

        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

I need to make a cycle for multylogin. It should in cycle in Login field paste one login from my property file with the same password for all users.
For example my property file have structure:

```
URL:http://barracuda-qa.ko.kodak.com/d2l/faces/Login.jsp
Login:Test1, Test2
Password:Abc123
```

So we should start browser 2 times and it'll login as Test1 - Abc123 and Test2 - Abc123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So we should start browser 2 times and it'll login as Test1 - Abc123
>   and Test2 - Abc123.

In short you will need to get the (Login) comma separated string from the properties file, split it and keep it in a list. Use it in a for loop.

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(config.getProperty("Login").split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Above code should  give you the needed list and then you can implement the multiple login as given below:

```
for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
        driver.get(config.getProperty("URL"));

        //here goes your multiple user name
        usernameEditBox.sendKeys(items.get(i).trim());

        //here is your same password
        passwordEditBox.sendKeys(config.getProperty("Password"));

        signinButton.click();
        logout.click();
}
```

You can check a full class view here: [ClickME](https://github.com/Chandan-Nayak/stackoverflow-files/blob/master/multiLogin)

Comment: it's ok, but how to make it start at the time together, and about 10 users?

Comment: and what is it, what it's doing? "split("\\s*,\\s*"))"

Comment: your question was to take multiple user/login form property file and use one password to cycle through, which is exactly what is done in the above code. About your second comment, I have explained what is does in the answer. If you are now asking about starting it at the same time, that is a different question! - check the full class view for more info

Answer (score 0):

**Not the answer, but a suggestion.**

The approach you have chosen, in my opinion, is rather strange.

When you are performing a **load testing with JMeter**, you send certain amount of requests for certain resources and check how well your server/application handles all the requests and how fast the results are produced.

When you are testing **UI with Selenium** the main focus is making sure that all the essential features of your web application are presented to a user in a browser window and are not crashed/hidden and all the necessary workflows can be completed using browser as a mean of comunication with server.

For load testing your server **doesn't care whether your GET/POST/PUT etc. requests are sent from browser or from a command line through telnet**, because in the end it will receive the same request and very costly process of opening browser to send a simple GET string becomes an obvious overkill.

The flow you are trying to test is easily implemented in JMeter itself.

Plus it becomes harder to load-test concurrently, which is one of the main JMeter advantages. Now you need to account for a language- or test-provider- specific concurrency issues.

I would recommend load testing purely from JMeter, as it's already robust and adding anything from outside in most cases is unnecesary, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: I know, this test I've posted here it's just a simple example. But I should write automation test and after run it on JMeter it's a company requirements.

Comment: FIght the system with logic) You can approximately replicate the same automation on JMeter as you do on Selenium and server would not know, but the efficiency gain is huge.